# Run code every second by using System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, loops, time

I am trying to run a line of code every second by using System.currentTimeMillis();.

The code:

```
     while(true){
           long var = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
           double var2 = var %2;

           if(var2 == 1.0){

               //code to run

           }//If():

        }//While
```

The code which I want to run, runs multiple times because var2 is set to 1.0 multiple times due to the infinite whole loop. I just want to run the code line when var2 is first set to 1.0, and then every time again when var2 becomes 1.0 after 0.0.

Comment: I should really start putting comments on loops and decisions like you have. Well done for that.

Comment: @Andy - please don't put comments on closing braces like that.  Use your IDE's "show matching brackets" and/or refactor the code so that you don't have blocks that are so long that you *need* to do this.

Comment: @StephenC, I think Andy was being sarcastic. His comment was not too helpful to the OP.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to busy wait for the seconds to change you can use the following.

```
long lastSec = 0;
while(true){
    long sec = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    if (sec != lastSec) {
       //code to run
       lastSec = sec;
    }//If():
}//While
```

A more efficient approach is to sleep until the next second.

```
while(true) {
    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //code to run
    Thread.sleep(1000 - millis % 1000);
}//While
```

An alternative is to use a ScheduledExecutorService

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // code to run
    }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// when finished
ses.shutdown();
```

The advantage of this approach is that

- you can have a number of tasks with different periods sharing the same thread.
- you can have non-repeating delay or asynchronous tasks.
- you can collect the results in another thread.
- you can shutdown the thread pool with one command.

Comment: Thanks I used the first option you gave

Answer (score 4):

I'd use the java [executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) libraries. You can create a [ScheduledPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool%28int%29) that takes a runnable and can run for any time period you want. For example

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyRunnable(), 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Will run the MyRunnable class every 5 seconds. MyRunnable must implement Runnable. The trouble with this is that it will (efficiently) create a new thread each time which may or may not be desirable.

Answer (score 2):

You should have to use [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and `java.util.TimerTask` class.

Comment: If code is not in UI thread(for obvious reason) he can also use Thread.sleep

Comment: The legacy timer and timer task APIs are terrible. There's no sane exception handling and once an exception occurs, the whole timer thread is killed. You'd have to re-run it. It's also sensitive to changes in system clock, you'd have to untouch the system clock (and turn off DST!). The modern java util concurrent executor service API doesn't have those peculiar problems.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Thread.sleep();` would be perfect for your case.

```
 while(true)
 {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // Waiting before run.
    // Actual work goes here.
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't run every second. This waits one second after completion. The run itself does not necessarily take 0 seconds. Imagine that the run takes 200ms, then it should actually have waited 800ms instead. Use the java util concurrent executor service instead.

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to halt the Java main class every second. Any way of doing it with System.currentTimemillis?

Comment: @BalusC you are right. but this answer is just for giving a tip to the OP. he should configure the sleeping time.

Answer (score 1):

preferred way:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

Then pass in Runnables like:

```
scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(myRunnable, initDelay, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

I wouldn't use the Timer. Schedulers are built to handle problems that Timers can cause. Also, the Thread.sleep is good for a simple program that you're writing quickly for proof of concept type things but I wouldn't use it in the enterprise world.