# Bad practice or not when running code every 5 seconds?

Tags: java, loops

I want my code to be ran every 5 seconds for example using:

```
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
          //Handle exception
    }
```

However, would it be bad practice to put a `while` loop around this that is ALWAYS true to make something always happen every 5 seconds or is this okay?

Comment: It seems more appropriate to use a cron rather than having your thread sleep for five seconds; after all, it could be interrupted.

Comment: Not necessarily, but it would be better to use a conditional variable that you can set externally in order to properly terminate the loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run code every second by using System.currentTimeMillis()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121885/run-code-every-second-by-using-system-currenttimemillis)

Comment: I would use a `ScheduledTaskExecutor` for this sort of thing.

Comment: It looks OK, as long as this is not in the GUI thread or something like that, so the application is frozen the five seconds.

Comment: Yeah... whether it's good practice to use `Thread.sleep()` at all is contingent upon there having been a good reason to explicitly create your own worker thread in the first place.  There often isn't.

Answer (score 5):

Use a scheduled executor for that matter:

```
ScheduledExecutorService pool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
pool.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> { System.out.println("Hello World"); }, 0l, 5l, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

[Click for the documentation of the ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't need it, but threads are created lazily in the `ThreadPoolExecutor` implementation, so this won't create any unneeded ones in case the OP uses less.

Comment: I know, but there's a `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

***I would use an executor:***

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    Runnable toRun = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("your code...");
        }
    };
ScheduledFuture<?> handle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(toRun, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

***OR as you have said with while loop:***

```
while(true)
 {
     try {
        Thread.sleep(5000); // Waiting before run.
        // Actual work goes here.
     } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
          //Handle exception
     }
 }
```

***OR even with a timer:***

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
int timeinterval = 10 * 1000;
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //This code is executed at every interval defined by timeinterval (eg 2 seconds)
  }
}, timeinterval);
```

Answer (score 0):

I often do something like this:

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    // do something
    Thread.sleep(DELAY);
}
```

In practice it's not much different from `while(true)`, because if the thread is interrupted the loop will run at most one more time, and then `sleep()` will throw an `InterruptedException`.

But the condition documents the intent.

Answer (score 0):

It is considered bad practice to use a `while` loop for this, because this is too low level. `Thread.sleep` is subject to [spurious wakeups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup) which will cause things to sometime run the task at the wrong interval.

There is also an issue with "drift". You task will, presumably, take longer than `0ms` to run. So if you want to run the task, starting every `5s`, then this start time will drift.

Best practice is to use a [`java.lang.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) (not a `javax.swing.Timer`) to run the task.

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do studff
    }
}, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5));
```

Or a `ScheduledExecutorService`, which is more flexible as it allows you to schedule and cancel tasks more easily.

```
final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ScheduledFuture<?> handle = executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> System.out.println(), 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The second example uses a lambda.